# How To Call a Java Stored Procedure In Oracle 10gR2?

Tags: java, oracle, java-stored-procedures

Here is my code:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE NOFORCE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "SCHEMA"."DigestUtils" AS
/* imports here... */

public class DigestUtils {

    private static final char[] hexCode = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    public static String sha512Hex(Clob c) throws MyException {
        // Code here ...
        return "Hex.string.here";
    }

    private static class MyException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8501244872025707585L;

        public MyException(Throwable cause) {
            super(cause);

            if ((cause instanceof SQLException) && !(cause instanceof SQLWarning) && (DriverManager.getLogWriter() != null)) {
                printStackTrace(DriverManager.getLogWriter());
            }
        }
    }
}
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sha512Hex RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'DigestUtils.sha512Hex(java.sql.Clob) return java.lang.String';
```

when I try to call the Java stored procedure from SQL like below:

```
select  clob_column, sha512Hex(clob_column)
from my_table
where id in (49917,49918,49919,60455)
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: numéro ou types d'arguments erronés dans appel à 'sha512Hex'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error on line 196, column 17 (translated from original message)
```

Here is the error line:

```
(l. 196) select  clob_column, sha1Hex(clob_column)
                              ^
                              |___ column 17
```

What am I missing?

**Oracle 10gR2**
**Java 1.4.2 (embedded in Oracle)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you describe your current function you'll see:

```
desc sha512Hex

Argument Name  Type     In/Out Default 
-------------- -------- ------ ------- 
<return value> VARCHAR2 OUT    unknown
```

Your PL/SQL function declaration needs to define the argument and its type too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sha512Hex(c CLOB) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'DigestUtils.sha512Hex(java.sql.Clob) return java.lang.String';

desc sha512Hex

Argument Name  Type     In/Out Default 
-------------- -------- ------ ------- 
<return value> VARCHAR2 OUT    unknown 
C              CLOB     IN     unknown
```

You can then call that as you were attempting to in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This answer completes [Alex Poole's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37467461/363573).

Here is how to describe a function with a plain SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
     argument_name
    ,pls_type
    --,data_type -- may contain useful info
    ,in_out
    ,default_value
FROM
   user_arguments -- replace with ALL_ARGUMENTS for functions you don't own
WHERE
   object_name = 'SHA1HEX'
ORDER BY 
   position
```

#### OUTPUT

```
ARGUMENT_NAME    PLS_TYPE       IN_OUT    DEFAULT_VALUE
---------------- -------------- --------- --------------
<null>           VARCHAR2       OUT       <null>
C                CLOB           IN        <null>
```

#### References

- [Oracle Database Administration : ALL_ARGUMENTS view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1014.htm)

Comment: I just used `describe` in SQL Developer, which also has `info`; the output is slightly different with SQL\*Plus's version of `describe`. But yes, if you don't have a client command available, this is what they do under the hood *8-)